# sas drop value through the whole data

Tags: sas

I want to turn invalid values to a single value and them print only the ID's of the obs that has these values=> I have multiple error is the second part (the loop), is it possible to fix somehow this code, or is it simply impossible to do that this way?

```
data comb8;set comb;
if q2 not in (1,2,3,4,5)then q2=666;
if q3 not in (1,2,3,4,5)then q3=666;
if q10 not in (1,2,3,4,5)then q10=666;
if gender not in(0,1)then gender=666;
if married not in(0,1)then married=666;
run;

data comb10; set comb8;
do i=1 to n;
if i NE 666 then drop(?????????);
end;
keep id;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure what the result you're after with the drop - do you just want to return a list of the observation numbers that have invalid values?

Comment: Hopefully the answer helps, but just to note - the error you have in your do loop was because your do loop doesn't reference any variables - it instead just checks `if 1 NE 666` and then `if 2 NE 666` etc up to "n" (which doesn't make sense in this case)... You need to first declare the variables in an array (`array Q q1-q10;`), and then use the array in the do loop (`if Q[i] NE 666 then drop() ;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping I've understood this right - the end result you're after is to just keep the obervation number of any observation that contains an invalid value for **any** of the criteria you're checking for? If so, try this:

```
data comb8(keep=id where=(not missing(obid)));
  set comb;
  if q2  not in (1,2,3,4,5) then obid=_n_;
  if q3  not in (1,2,3,4,5) then obid=_n_;
  if q10 not in (1,2,3,4,5) then obid=_n_;
  if gender not in(0,1) then obid=_n_;
  if married not in(0,1) then obid=_n_;
run;
```

`_n_` is an automatic variable that identifies the observation number that has been loaded in from the set statement. You can set obid to this value when an issue is found and then use `(where=(not missing(obid)))` to only keep the observations that had invalid values

Just in case it's of help to anyone else later on...

```
data comb8;set comb;
if q2 not in (1,2,3,4,5)then q2=666;
if q3 not in (1,2,3,4,5)then q3=666;
if q10 not in (1,2,3,4,5)then q10=666;
if gender not in(0,1)then gender=666;
if married not in(0,1)then married=666;
run;

data comb10(keep=obid where=(not missing(obid)));
  set comb8;
  Array Q q1-q10 gender married . ;
  do i=1 to dim(Q) ;
    if Q[i] EQ 666 then obid=_n_;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: how does the _n_ var knows to identify the value '666' though?

Comment: I thought 666 was just a temporary assignment - my mistake! Hope my other comment regarding the array do loop is enough for you to crack it - otherwise let me know and can send it over

Comment: just a quick question, where you array Q, does it stand for => going through all observations, in the following vars...?

Comment: Yes the array statement assigns a numeric reference to each variable - so q1=1 and gender=11. The do loop then runs from array variable 1 through to the max number variable in the Q array (in my example: 12)